# How can I host my nord.js project on hostinger on vps and I use domain as GoDaddy

Tags: hosting

I am facing problem to hosting my website on hostinger vps have some problem in preview and how to connect with domain.

Solution how to host my website on hostinger and how to connect with GoDaddy.If some one help me plzz help me I am final year collage student of B.tech